# Clearing accumulated session data

Tags: php

So there is a searchbar with autocomplete, when user searches for something he can add it to list below which accumulates all added variables using session. How to make all of those session variables clear after user uses refresh browser or clear button?

Comment: You can always set those session variables as empty ex. $_SESSION['foo'] = '';

Answer (score 1):

you can use `unset()` or `session_destroy()` on click of your clear button